# "I will never leave an enemy behind" What does this coach mean by that before the football game?

Tags: meaning-in-context, transcription

I happened to watch this inspiring speech **I Am A Champion** delivered by Coach Johnathan Flowers.

[At 01:23](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAPv_DhIFkQ) did he say that "*I will never leave an enemy behind*" which has particular meaning for football.

But I am a bit confused by the transcript from YouTube "*I will never leave it there to be behind*"

or I just got it wrong and he said other words similar to these?

Comment: I'm sure the guy himself just got carried away and confused. He really does say *I will never leave **an enemy** behind*, but I think he's accidentally slipped into the mode of a military commander robustly telling his troops / supporters *We will never leave **a man** behind* (we will defend and if necessary rescue all of our soldiers). Essentially, he "misspoke" in the heat of the moment.

Comment: I CV'd because your title asks one thing but the body of your question asks something else, so I was confused. Please ask only one question and make it clear.

Comment: The guy is just ranting and he made a mistake in what he said. (Incidentally this speech typifies everything that is wrong with American sports.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement:

> I will never leave an enemy behind.

comes from a military context. In that context, it means

> I will kill all of the enemy, I will not leave any alive.

The statement:

> I will never leave a man behind.

also comes from a military context. In that context it means:

> I will not abandon a wounded soldier, rather I will take such a person along, to be treated and rescued if possible.

This coach is extensively using a military metaphor for sports. He repeatedly refers to the playing field as "the field of battle".  He uses other phrases that might be (and have been) used by military commanders addressing troops before battle. Some would question the appropriateness of this extended metaphor. But whether one likes it or not, one must keep that context in mind to understand the meaning of this speech.

As I listen to the video of the speech, I hear the coach as in fact saying: "*I will never leave an enemy behind.*" but it is easy to mis-hear statements in such a video. He seems to be reading from a prepared text. It may be that that text has been published. I have not searched for it.

Comment: The audio is not quite clear to identify for me. Appreciate your efforts. That make sense to take military context into consideratain.

Comment: I could vividly imagine a picture in my mind that no enemy could possibly pass through the defensive construction built by a group of these solders.

Comment: At 00:52, Did the coach said "I will **gladly** go out into the field of battle" or "I will **gradually** go out into the field of battle". Is that also from a military context?

Comment: @Stats Cruncher "Field of Battle" sounds military to me.

Comment: Does that mean **gladually** instead?

Comment: @Stats Cruncher I don't know of any English word spelled "*gladually*". The word "*gradually*" means roughly "slowly" or "by stages".

Comment: My fault. Sorry and thank you for instuction. Does the coach mean" I will **gradually** go out into the field of battle" or other words such as **gladly**?

Comment: @Stats Cruncher I heard it as "gladly", but it doesn't matter much to this question in my view. In either case the military analogy seems clear.

Comment: Many other words are not that clear to me. Such as "no one will **defy** me" or "no one will **define** me". and"I will never **give up not until Ive given everything I got**" or "I will never **go home, not knowing giving everything that I have got**." (American )Football is like war. I have not experienced that.